# Tensorflow: data api for big datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I'm learning about neural networks reading the book "hands on machine learning with scikit learn keras tensorflow" and the page 410 the author shows the following function saying it is a small helper function: it will create and return a dataset that will efficiently load data from multiple CSV files, then shuffle it, preprocess it and batch it. And it is a good intput pipe for learge datasets that don't fit in memory(ram).

I tried to run the function with 3 small files pretending they are the training set and the thing is the entire "training set"(all three files together) was loaded in memory. More precisaly the function tf.data.TextLineDataset() is reading the whole file. I though it would load in batches lets say, 32 instances from hard drive to ram  at the time but is not whats hapening.

So I don't understand whats happening here. Why it is reading the whole dataset?

```
X_mean,X_std = [...] # mean and scale of each feature in the training set n_inputs = 8


def preprocess(line):
    defs = [0.] * n_inputs + [tf.constant([], dtype=tf.float32)]
    fields = tf.io.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=defs)
    x = tf.stack(fields[:-1])
    y = tf.stack(fields[-1:])
    return (x - X_mean) / X_std, y


def csv_reader_dataset(filepaths, n_readers=5, shuffle_buffer_size=10000, n_parse_threads=5, batch_size=32):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filepaths).repeat(repeat)
    dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda filepath: tf.data.TextLineDataset(filepath).skip(1), cycle_length=n_readers)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(shuffle_buffer_size)
    dataset = dataset.map(preprocess, num_parallel_calls=n_parse_threads)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset.prefetch(1)


train_set = csv_reader_dataset(train_filepaths)
valid_set = csv_reader_dataset(valid_filepaths)
test_set = csv_reader_dataset(test_filepaths)


model = keras.models.Sequential([...])
model.compile([...])
model.fit(train_set, steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) // batch_size, 
        epochs=10, validation_data=valid_set, validation_steps=len(X_valid) // batch_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

For reading multiple CSV files from disk as necessary you can use the `make_csv_dataset` function.

```
train_ds = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    tf.io.gfile.glob("data/multiple/*.csv"), 
    batch_size = 10, 
    column_names = None, 
    column_defaults= [0,0,0,0,0.,"a",0],
    label_name='target', 
    select_columns = ['age', 'sex', 'cp', 'trestbps','oldpeak','thal', 'target'],  
    shuffle=True, 
    shuffle_seed=101, 
    
)
```

For more information see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/make_csv_dataset).